# Use ::after selector to show line number but also display a <a> element next to it when hovering over the containing table td cell

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to show line number next to source code in my web page, I'm using two table columns, one for line number, another for source code, and I have the following requirement:

1. show a special icon before the line number when mouse is hovering
   over it
2. the special icon ('x' in the code below) is a anchor tag, and I'd
   like the anchor to expand to the whole *td* cell
3. when selecting the source code, do **NOT** select and copy line
   number

If I don't have requirement 3, I can simply show line number in the `<a>` element and expand it to the full td. I managed to make things sort of work, my code is below:

HTML

```
<table id='file-table' class='table table-hover table-condensed'>
  <tr>
    <!--other td-->
    <td data-line-number='1'>
      <a type='button' role='button' ng-click='doSomething()'>x</a>
    </td>
    <!--other td-->
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
/*the concerning column is the 4th in the table*/
#file-table tr td:nth-child(4) {
    width: 4%;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}
#file-table tr td:nth-child(4)::after {
    content: attr(data-line-number);
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    text-align: right;
    display: block;
}
#file-table tr td:nth-child(4) > a {
    display: none;
}
#file-table tr td:nth-child(4):hover > a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
}
```

So the idea is use ::after to show line number in `<td>` and hide `<a>` until hover over it, when `<a>` will display and expand to 100% width. However, the problem I have now is even the line number displays ok: [image]

when I hover over it, 'x' shows but breaks td to two lines: [image]

What am I doing wrong here? How can I make sure 'x' is shown on the same line, if that's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you need to worry about a special data attribute as it's possible to achieve the line number using pure CSS and the `counter-increment` property.

Having the hyperlink appear on hover and (I assume) overtop any other text will require some absolute positioning but can be achieved as follows:

```css
#file-table { 
 counter-reset: line;
}

#file-table tr:before {
 counter-increment: line;
 content: counter(line);
 display: inline-block;
 color: #888;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 12px 8px;
 font-size: 0.5em;
}

#file-table td {
 position: relative; 
 width: 100%;
}

#file-table td a { 
 display: none; 
}

#file-table td:hover a {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 2;
 top: 0;
 background: #eee;
 padding: 5px 2px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="file-table" class="table table-hover table-condensed">
<tr><td>Line 1<a type='button' role='button' ng-click='doSomething()'>x</a></td></tr>
<tr><td>Line 2<a type='button' role='button' ng-click='doSomething()'>x</a></td></tr>
<tr><td>Line 3<a type='button' role='button' ng-click='doSomething()'>x</a></td></tr>
<tr><td>Line 4<a type='button' role='button' ng-click='doSomething()'>x</a></td></tr>
<tr><td>Line 5<a type='button' role='button' ng-click='doSomething()'>x</a></td></tr>
<tr><td>Line 6<a type='button' role='button' ng-click='doSomething()'>x</a></td></tr>
<tr><td>Line 7<a type='button' role='button' ng-click='doSomething()'>x</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

Some considerations:

- Bootstrap's hover effect on tables is an RGBA value.  In order to
  achieve the hyperlink covering 100% of the table cell, you have to
  implement another background.  The two overlap and create a
  darker-than-standard color so you may need to fiddle with that.
- The table cells will need a defined width or the line numbers in the `:before` tend to result in some odd placement.

Comment: Adding `position: relative;` and `position: absolute;` works, can you please explain what does z-index do? I played with `z-index` and `top` but they don't seem to make a difference.

Comment: `z-index` functions as a way to indicate layers; the higher the number the higher on the stack it appears.  In this case I'm using it to ensure that your `<a>` appears above the rest of the text in the `<td>` when you hover over the cell